# Using variables in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

In my composer.json I have the following:

```
"repositories": [        
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "aaemnnosttv/wordpress-core-phpunit-includes",
            "type": "wordpress-tests-core",
            "version": "5.0.2",
            "source": {
                "type": "svn",
                "url": "https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/",
                "reference": "tags/5.0.2/tests/phpunit/includes/"
            },
            "require": {
                "aaemnnosttv/wordpress-tests-core-installer": "~0.1"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "aaemnnosttv/wordpress-core-phpunit-includes": "5.0.2"
}
```

Unfortunately I have to repeat myself in specifying the version of the package. Once in the "version" line, once in the "reference" line and once in the "aaemnnosttv/wordpress-core-phpunit-includes" line.

Is there a way of using a composer variable so that I don't have to repeat myself?

Comment: It's a JSON configuration file so I cannot imagine that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

composer file is json and **JSON does not allow variable referencing.**

but because you are using [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag in your question, I suggest a example for handle it, maybe it can help you.

create PHP file to set array of environments of composer.

```
$variable = "aaemnnosttv/wordpress-core-phpunit-includes";
$version = "5.0.2";
$composer = [
    "repositories" => [
        [
            "type" => "package",
            "package" => [
                "name" => $variable
                // whatever is in
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "require" => [
            $variable => $version
    ]
];
```

then save the array as json in *composer.json* file.

```
file_put_contents('compose.json', json_encode($composer));
```

if your want to just edit composer file you must read it and the edit:

```
$composer = json_decode(file_get_contents('compose.json', true));

$variable = "aaemnnosttv/wordpress-core-phpunit-includes";
$version = "5.0.2";
$composer["repositories"][0]["package"]["name"] = $variable;
$composer["require"][$variable] = $version;
```